# When to use Mongrel as web server for Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mongrel

When I started my first *bigger* Rails application, I chose to use **Apache** (with Passenger), because I already had some experience with it with PHP, but I don't have any deep knowledge of deploying Rails applications.

How would one choose web server for a Rails app?

**Are there any main differences between Apache and Mongrel?**
Or is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280155/best-practices-for-new-rails-deployments-on-linux

Comment: If you chose not to use Passenger is there then any reason at all to use Mongrel instead of for example Thin nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, two popular setups are:

- Apache + passenger
- Apache + mongrel (Apache sending requests to your mongrel cluster)

Yes, It is a matter of taste.
You made the good choice with Passenger for your first app as it is far easier to setup.
It is the #1 recommended option on ROR official Website.
Performance is also very good.

Using mongrel is still a good option but it is harder to setup and administrate.
You will need to make sure you are running your rails app against a cluster of mongrel and not only one mongrel instance (for performance/concurrent request reason). Meaning adminstration of your apache + administration of your mongrels.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use mongrel.

The reason you see lots of sites/tutorials using mongrel is.. it was a good choice before Passenger.

Passenger is better on the performance side, dead easy to install and no (for the 90% cases) managing is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do Nginx + Mongrel cluster. (I don't recommend it though.)  Go with Phusion Passenger.  It's pretty easy to setup and it's fast.  No reason not to use it.

I use Passenger with Nginx.  Besides just the web server, also look into using Ruby Enterprise Edition.  It's going to save you a good amount of memory. ~30%.  [Ruby Enterprise Edition.](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/)